# install Grunt is Failing while running from Gradle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gradle, gruntjs

I am having a list of Gradle tasks which will execute npminstall and grunt_clean, grunt_build tasks etc. I don't have npm command prompt externally available to run any npm commands. Need to run via Gradle tasks only.

We have an internal repo of node 'V.0.12.7' installed. Hence while running '**npm-install**' am facing the below issue.

```
> npm ERR! node v0.12.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
> 
> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> If you need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!    
> <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

And while running **"install Grunt"** task, getting the below error.

```
> npm ERR! node v0.12.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3 npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
> 
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings'
> peerDependencies requirements! npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> jit-grunt@0.9.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-karma@0.11.2 wants grunt@0.4.x npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-newer@1.1.1 wants grunt@~0.4.1 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-ng-constant@1.1.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-connect-proxy@0.2.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-autoprefixer@3.0.3 wants grunt@~0.4.2 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid
> Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.8.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid
> Peer grunt-filerev@2.3.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-usemin@3.0.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-ng-annotate@1.0.1 wants grunt@~0.4.5 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
> grunt-contrib-connect@0.10.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
```

And please find my "package.Json"

```
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.x",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "0.5.7",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "3.0.3",
    "grunt-concurrent": "2.0.0",
    "grunt-connect-proxy": "0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.12.3",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "2.3.1",
    "grunt-jscpd": "0.0.11",
    "grunt-karma": "0.11.2",
    "grunt-modernizr": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-multi":"0.0.6",
    "grunt-newer": "1.1.1",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-text-replace": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "2.0.0" ....
```

Without "**installGrunt**", Grunt Build will fail, so while run "**npminstall**", the grunt version is "0.4.5", but while running "install Grunt" the grunt version is updating to "1.0.1"

tried to delete node_modules, cache etc, but nothing worked, don't think i can update node also.

Any small help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.